# Counting and remove strings - java

Tags: java

How do I delete all the uneccessary information and just print SAMPLE COMPANY. Please note that this value nay change. The only static values in this string are :name:,:address:,:contact:

:name:SAMPLE COMPANY:address:#79 Landmark  City  Columbia:contact:‎1234567

Thanks!!

Comment: Is this a single line of data you are dealing with, or are there many such lines?

Comment: Is going to be hard to help you if you dont provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `string.split(":")` and read the third object from array to get your value

Comment: Not really, second value would be `name` in this example (since only trailing empty String are exclused). But the logic is still correct

Comment: Agreed @AxelH. Edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: This would fail when the company name has a `:` in it. I would use indexOf and substring methods. Anyway clean solution +1.

Comment: I agree with @UmaKanth but then using `indexOf` would not really help, using regex would be simpler.

Comment: @UmaKanth And what if the name contains `:address:`? The problem is not with this answer; the parameters of the question haven't​ been made clear.

Comment: @shmosel Generally company name doesn't have `:address` in it. But, a companies subsidiary can have a `:` in it. However, I agree with you about the clarity of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] sa = yourstring.split(':');

string newstring = sa[1];
```

Then just print the newstring. You said the company name will change but the strings will always be in that format so if the company name is always in the second location then this will work even if the company name changes.

Comment: Same comment as [Poorvi Nigotiya](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43840066/4391450)'s answer, since this is the same ... The seconds value will be `name` not the value you seeks. See how `String.split` really works.

Answer (score 0):

Lets use a regex with some [capturing groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) since you have label in your `String`.

Here is a simple idea of how it works :

```
String s = ":name:SAMPLE COMPANY:address:#79 Landmark City Columbia:contact:‎1234567";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":name:(.*):address:(.*):contact:‎(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println("Name : " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Address : " + m.group(2));
    System.out.println("Contact : " + m.group(3));
}
```

And this will output

```
Name : SAMPLE COMPANY
Address : #79 Landmark City Columbia
Contact : 1234567
```

Comment: Will this work if the address contains the string `:address:`?

Comment: @shmosel This could work if we define the groups better I suppose but honestly this is unlikely to find that pattern in an address.

Comment: I agree that it's unlikely, but the same might be true for a single colon. Or there might be an escape sequence. It's all speculation until OP refines his question.

Comment: @shmosel Please note that the answer provided is only showing that this is possible. Not that this is the answer for his specific problem. I almost never provide answer matching 100% a problem, OP's still have some adaptation to do.